# Set content type of part of multipart/mixed request in CURL

Tags: curl

I want to send json request and several files in one http request. I'm using `multipart/mixed` request for that

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -F "request=@body.json; type=application/json" -F "file1=@2.xml" -F "file2=@2.pdf" -X POST hostName
```

`request` field has `application/json` content type and by that indication I define that this part is json request and other parts are files.

My question is how to inline request body in curl request. I try to use

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -F "request={"param1": "value1"}" -F "file1=@2.xml" -F "file2=@2.pdf" -X POST hostName
```

but content type of `request` will be `plain/text`

Answer (score 13):

You can add content-type information after semicolon:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -F "request={"param1": "value1"};type=application/json"
```

Answer (score 8):

To attach both a payload and a file using curl command, some like this will do.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" \
-F "somepayload={\"name\":\"mypayloadname\"};type=application/json" \
-F "uploadfile=@somevalid.xml" http://localhost:8080/path/topost
```

Make sure you escape the payload content and somevalid.xml should be there in the same directory where curl is executed or replace it with valid path to the file.

Comment: With my curl version (7.52.1), it still valid `-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"`, having json content in an external file too, that is to say using `-F "info=@path/content.json;type=application/json"  -F "file=@path/doc.pdf; type=application/pdf"`