# Is it possible to attach file in POST Json?

Tags: json, ajax, http, http-headers

I have a heap of data in format JSON(Serialized object).
I send this data to server by `POST` method with header: `Content-Type: application/json`.

Is it possible to attach file to body request and send at once. Or JSON data sugggests sending only text data?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "attach file"? What do you think the differences are between sending a text file and sending textual data?

Comment: Attach I mean send file in POST request together with text data.

Comment: That doesn't clarify your question. [Edit] it to show how you actually issue the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the file inside the json object as a base64 string:

```
{
"file":"dGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgc2FtcGxl..." 
}
```

Later you can open the file with something like:

```
document.location = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + file
```

Comment: Then how to handle `file` in server side? If it is in base54 string? It will be POST field?

Comment: well, in your case you can use `multipart/form-data` to send the file to the server.

Comment: So, this is header `multipart/form-data `? also use content-type: application/json?

Answer (score 5):

In this context, the [`content-type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231031/set-content-type-of-part-of-multipart-mixed-request-in-curl) header aims to describe the type of data in the request body.
If you use `application/json` the server will expect a JSON body.

If your goal is to send a single request with a JSON object and a file, you can either encode the file in the JSON structure (Probably base64. See: [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64))

```
{
  ...
  file: "encoded_content",
  ...
}
```

Or you can use the content type [`multipart/form-data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#multipartform-data).
A multipart is a part containing other part.
The first subpart may be the JSON strucuture. The second one may be the file