# How to passing data Model and file in web api c#

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-3.0

I passing image file and json object skills to CreateResume API but object skills have no data.

So how do I get skills data in post API? thank you.

[image: postman passing data]

[image: my api]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479129/upload-file-on-server-webfolder-and-post-json-data-at-the-same-using-asp-net-web/64480196#64480196

Comment: You need to pass skills as `skills[0].SkillName` as key and `C#` as value